# Android and big extra size

Tags: android

I m actually facing a problem with the intent extras size. In fact I need to get a nested object containing ~2000 objects.

So, when trying to transmit this intent, I got errors telling me that the size of the object is too big.

My question is : what is the best way to manage it, without using the ugly method, corresponding to store every object in a class using the static way.

What is the best way to transmit big informations between activities.

Thanks for advance

Comment: May be you can save all the data in database and retrieve in next activity if its ~2000 objects.

Comment: Pretty much as above, write to local storage by serializing everying or better yet, use a local database and then query as necessary. Every object has a parent and a child/children so it shouldn't even be hard to identify what you need.

Comment: What do you think about the "ugly" method. it seems that many people is using this way...